# How to store data in PostgreSQL already sorted

Tags: postgresql, sorting

Is there some way to hint PostgreSQL Database to store data in a sorted manner?

For example, I have this SQL schema:

```
create table DataHolder(
    name text,
    path ltree primary key
);

create table Datas(
    time int primary key,
    foreign_dataholder_id ltree references Exchange(path)
);
```

And I can populate it like so:

```
insert into DataHolder(name, path) values ('A', 'Sec1.SubSec1');
insert into DataHolder(name, path) values ('B', 'Sec1.SubSec2');
insert into DataHolder(name, path) values ('C', 'Sec2.SubSec1');
...

insert into Datas (time, foreign_exchange_id) values (1513889449, 'Sec1.SubSec1');
insert into Datas (time, foreign_exchange_id) values (1513889451, 'Sec1.SubSec1');
...
```

So I have some DataHolder table that stores some tree like data containers like `Sec1.SubSec1`, for each of these containers, I have a lot of Data.

But the crucial part is that the data always have it's primary key as a unix timestamp, and it is always queried as a time range region of interest and sorted in ascendant order.

For example:

```
select * from Datas where foreign_dataholder_id = 'Sec1.SubSec1' and
  time >= 1513889450 and time <= 1513889451 order by time asc;
```

Since I always query in that manner, it would be the best, performance wise, to tell PostgreSQL to already store these data internally sorted by `Datas.time` in ascendant order so it doesn't need to do that in every query I do.

Is that possible? If not, is there some other way to design these tables?

Edit:

I though about some solutions, an array for example could work since I can always guarantee it's sorted and the majority of my additions to it would be at it's end where no sort is needed.

But, since there is occasionally insertions in the middle of the table, it could be somewhat difficult to do it or not efficient.. I don't know.

Another idea would be a linked list, but I'm not aware if PostgreSQL supports this data type or how to use.

Comment: Perhaps a [B-Tree index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/indexes-ordering.html) may help here.

Comment: I guess this can be solved by adding an index to the date field, so when you search your database, it will only search in the index. (not very much experience with PostgreSQL, only m-sql)

Comment: As noted by JNevill and Mr Zach, if you create an index on "Datas"."time", your queries should be able to take advantage of that. Also. you can [CLUSTER](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-cluster.html) your table using that index, which rewrites the table according to the indexed attributes (ascending order by default). Be aware this is a blocking and I/O intensive operation, and that it rewrites the _existing_ data only. Future rows being inserted or updated will not necessarily be in the desired order.

Comment: Using a B-tere index did the trick, thanks a lot, can you write it as a answer instead of a comment so I can select it as resolved?